# How to grab a class generated in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some select tags in javascript but now I want to customise the style with jQuery. The problem that I have is that I can't access the class of select tag. Does anyone have any idea why is this?

```
nextOneSelectorHtml = 
            '<select ' +
                'class="dropdown" ' + 
                'id="dd" ' + 
                'data-selector-level="' + (currentSelectLevel+1) + '" ' + 
                'data-path="' + strPath + '" ' + 
                'onchange="onFsSelectChange(this)"' + 
            '><option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>';
....
```

Now if I am doing

```
$('dropdown').css( "background-color: #000000" );
```

there is no effect

Comment: what are you doing with `nextOneSelectorHtml` and when are you calling `$('.dropdown').css( "background-color", "#000000" );` - make sure you are calling `.css()` after `nextOneSelectorHtml` is added to the dom

Comment: `nextOneSelectorHtml` I am generating dropdown boxes for multiple arrays. ex(first dropdown contain 4 folders. select one then show another dropdown with folders inside it. select another one and show another dropdown with files inside)

Comment: `$('.dropdown').css( "background-color", "#000000" );` this is not what I actually call. I call something to convert my style tag in ul to be easier to style it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/azxxh37y/1/ - looks fine

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a class selector `.` and change the format of argument passed in `.css()` method. First argument should be CSS property name and then next one should be its value:

```
$('.dropdown').css( "background-color", "#000000" ); //or .css({"background-color": "#000000"});
// ^^ Class selector needed
```